# Oracle comment to Find first charater start with Alpha and second with numeric

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have table called `DOM`column name `position`

I have below list of values in Position column

> SN125A,A1234,SSD123,B12347,SDDF234,11123,E1O123,B12345

my requirement is to find the positions whose First letter is Alpha and second letter is numeric.

So My expectation Positions is

> A1234,B12347,E1O123,B12345

Once I find these position then I need to remove the first character  of the above positions

So my final output should be :

> 1234,12347,1O123,12345 (removed the alpha from above positions)

How do we achieve this in Oracle.

I tried the below `REGEXP_LIKE(POSITIONS, '[A-Za-z]')` in my query but I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should match the beginning of the line `^` and also test for following digits

```
^[A-Za-z][0-9]
```

You can so add a third parameter to make the matching [case-insensitive](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm#i1048942):

```
REGEXP_LIKE (POSITIONS, '^[A-Z][0-9]', 'i');
```

You can remove the first char by using [SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm)

```
SUBSTR(POSITIONS, 2) AS pos
```

Answer (score 0):

`dom` is the table name,  `position` is the column name

```
select * from dom;

position
----------
SN125A
A1234
SSD123
B12347
SDDF234
11123
E1O123
B12345

8 rows selected.




      1  select substr(position, 2,length(position)) from dom
      2* where regexp_like(position,'^[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]')
    SQL> /

    SUBSTR(position,2,LENGTH(position))
    --------------------------------------------
    1234
    12347
    1O123
    12345
```

Comment: this can also done as

select 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(regexp_substr(position,'^[A-Z][0-9]+[A-Z]*[0-9]+',1,1,'i'),'[0-9]+[A-Z]*[0-9]+',1,1) 
from dom